# Android RecyclerView.Adapter onCreateViewHolder() working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView.Adapter but I am little confused regarding working of its method `onCreateViewHolder`.

```
  @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    if(viewType==TYPE_ITEM) {

        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_common_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(mView);
        return vh;

    } else {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_uncommon_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolderFooter vh = new ViewHolderFooter(mView);
        return vh;

    }
}
```

So incase I have 10 items in my list so for each item this method will be called and every time a new `ViewHolder` will be created of course it'll one time for each view but now my question is when we were using `ListView` and `BaseAdapter` with them we store `ViewHolder` in tag and use that. We don't create `ViewHolder` for each item.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

            if(convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);
                    mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
                    convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
            } else {
                    mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            mViewHolder.tvTitle = detail(convertView, R.id.tvTitle, myList.get(position).getTitle());
            mViewHolder.tvDesc  = detail(convertView, R.id.tvDesc,  myList.get(position).getDescription());
            mViewHolder.ivIcon  = detail(convertView, R.id.ivIcon,  myList.get(position).getImgResId());

            return convertView;
    }
```

So are we not creating extra viewholders object. Please help me understand the pros and cons.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`onCreateViewHolder` only creates a new view holder when there are no existing view holders which the `RecyclerView` can reuse. So, for instance, if your `RecyclerView` can display 5 items at a time, it will create 5-6 `ViewHolders`, and then automatically reuse them, each time calling `onBindViewHolder`.

Its similar to what your code in the `ListView` does (checking if `convertView` is `null`, and if not, grabbing the existing `ViewHolder` from the tag), except, with `RecyclerView`, this is all done automatically.

I suppose this is one of the pros with using a `RecyclerView` - you don't need to worry so much about reusing `ViewHolders` as you do with `ListView`. The con is, `RecyclerView` is very customisable, but has very little built in functionality - unlike `ListView` which is not very customisable, but has a lot of built in functionality.

Comment: So it means it'll generate a viewholder for each item and then use that holder each time for that cell of list. right?

Comment: Thanks Gil, I have one more question in RecyclerView.Adapter but for that i'll put a separate question on stack overflow.

Comment: i have gone through some document which are mentioned for abstract method onCreateViewHolder.        
The new ViewHolder will be used to display items of the adapter using
         {@link #onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int)}. 
Since it will be re-used to display different items in the data set, it is a good idea to cache references to sub views of the View to avoid unnecessary {@link View#findViewById(int)} calls. So how can we cache references to sub views?

Comment: Your ViewHolder should be doing this. When a ViewHolder is created, it gets a reference to the main view its holding in the constructor. Then, your custom ViewHolder should grab all the subviews (labels, images, etc) even in the constructor method. Remember that a ViewHolder is only created when there is no existing ViewHolder to reuse, and so creation of Views will follow the same logic.

Comment: Right now i am initialising my subview in constructor 
  public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTvSectionName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        }
So  it mean that my textview should be initialised only once but when i am debugging it going every time in the constructor of ViewHolder to initialising my textview. Is it right way?

Comment: As i am not getting the point that when every time viewholder object is created by calling its constructor for each item then how reusability of viewHolder object is working? Is it like that a particular viewHolder object binds to a cell and reused only for that cell?

Comment: One of the most horrifying API's ever written, if you could even call it that.  Just to render a simple list of items, you're required to know absolutely EVERYTHING about the inner workings of `ViewHolders` and `RecyclerView`s and `LayoutInflaters` and `ViewGroups` and `Context`.  Oh, my - indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

**--> Create a constructor :**

/**
 * Created by Deepak Sharma on 31/10/17.
 */

```
public class StoreListAdapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Collection<T> mItems;
    private Context context;
    private int mLayout;
    IClickable iClickable;
    private boolean isAnimationAllowed;
    private StoreSearchFilter<T> mSearchFilter;

    public StoreListAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void setData(Collection<T> items, boolean isAnimationAllowed)
    {
        mItems = items;
        this.isAnimationAllowed = isAnimationAllowed;
    }

    public void setCallback(int layout, IClickable iClickable)
    {
        this.mLayout = layout;
        this.iClickable = iClickable;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(mLayout, viewGroup, false);
        iClickable.init(view);

        StoreListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new StoreListAdapter.ViewHolder(view);    
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
//        viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams().width = width;
        viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams().height = height+24;

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StoreListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        iClickable.execute(viewHolder, mItems.toArray()[i],viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        if (isAnimationAllowed)
            setAnimation(viewHolder.itemView, i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size()>0?mItems.size():0;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mSearchFilter == null)
            mSearchFilter = new StoreSearchFilter<T>((ArrayList<StoreModel>) mItems, new IFilteredList<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onListFiltered(ArrayList<T> list) {
                    setData(list, false);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        return mSearchFilter;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView mTextView;
        //private CheckBox mCheckBox;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

            // Handle item click and set the selection
            /*v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Redraw the old selection and the new
                    notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);
                    selectedItem = getLayoutPosition();
                    notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);
                }
            });*/
        }

    }

    public interface IClickable<T> {
        public void init(View view);
        public void execute(StoreListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, T object, int position);
    }

    /**
     * Here is the key method to apply the animation
     */
    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
    {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
    }

}
```

**--> In you Activity/Fragment :**

```
ArrayList<StoreModel> mStoreList = new ArrayList<>();
 mStoreListAdapter = new StoreListAdapter(getActivity());
        boolean isAnimate = false;
        mStoreListAdapter.setData(mStoreList, isAnimate);
```

then call callback

```
mStoreListAdapter.setCallback(R.layout.store_item, new StoreListAdapter.IClickable() {
            @Override
            public void init(View view) {
                //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Initialized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void execute(StoreListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object object, int position) {
                final StoreModel model = (StoreModel) object;

                View view = viewHolder.itemView;
                StoreListAdapter.ViewHolder holder = viewHolder;

                final CoordinatorLayout fabGameview = (CoordinatorLayout) view;
                final CardView cardView = (CardView) fabGameview.findViewById(R.id.store_item_cardview);

                TextView txtStoreName = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.txtStoreName);
                TextView txtStoreAddress = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.txtStoreAddress);
                TextView txtStoreCity = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.txtStoreCity);
                TextView txtPrizes = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrizes);
                txtStoreName.setText(model.getStoreName());
                txtStoreAddress.setText(model.getStoreAddress());
                txtStoreCity.setText(model.getStoreCity());
                txtPrizes.setText(String.valueOf(model.getPrizesAvailable()));

                LinearLayout linearDetails = (LinearLayout) cardView.findViewById(R.id.linearDetails);
                LinearLayout linearPrize = (LinearLayout) cardView.findViewById(R.id.linearPrize);

                if (clickedMarkerModel != null && clickedMarkerModel == model) {
                    holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
//                    holder.itemView.setPressed(true);
//                    linearDetails.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
//                    linearPrize.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
//                    mRecyclerStore.stopScroll();
                } else {
                    holder.itemView.setSelected(false);
//                    holder.itemView.setPressed(false);
//                    linearDetails.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.store_selector));
//                    linearPrize.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.store_selector));
                }

                // TODO Here scroll recycler view upto selected item
                /*mRecyclerStore.smoothScrollToPosition(mStoreListAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);*/

                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isAddedToBackStack = true;
                        StoreDetailsAndProductListFragment storeDetailsAndProductListFragment = new StoreDetailsAndProductListFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putParcelable(ExtrasUtil.STORE, model);
                        storeDetailsAndProductListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        showOtherFragment(storeDetailsAndProductListFragment, getActivity().getFragmentManager(), isAddedToBackStack);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        mRecyclerStore.setAdapter(mStoreListAdapter);
```